# Imap-open isn't Connecting to Gmail - SELinux Problem

Tags: php, imap, selinux, imap-open, php-imap

Hi I'm Working on some code to imap some accounts from Gmail into a LAMP server I have done it before and now try to use same code but unusefully ok I have all day reading a lot of it here and this is what I have done until now.

I have enable imap forwarding on gmail. from here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en&authuser=7&visit_id=637046170242826287-1928730887&rd=2

I have allowed access for less secure apps on Google Account

I have set 2-Step Verification: ON + Created app password

any ways does two last are the same thing.

Well, I try the connection like this:

```
curl -v --insecure  --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993" --user "myuser4@gmail.com:mypassword"
```

and get

```
    * About to connect() to imap.gmail.com port 993 (#0)
    *   Trying 2607:f8b0:400c:c0d::6d...
    * Connected to imap.gmail.com (2607:f8b0:400c:c0d::6d) port 993 (#0)
    * Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
    * skipping SSL peer certificate verification
    * SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    * Server certificate:
    *       subject: CN=imap.gmail.com,O=Google LLC,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
    *       start date: Sep 05 20:13:16 2019 GMT
    *       expire date: Nov 28 20:13:16 2019 GMT
    *       common name: imap.gmail.com
    *       issuer: CN=GTS CA 1O1,O=Google Trust Services,C=US
    < * OK Gimap ready for requests from 2806:10be:3:2538:adb4:f65f:6c54:4264 j15mb13295787vsf
    > B CAPABILITY
    < * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
    < B OK Thats all she wrote! j15mb13295787vsf
    > C AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
    < + 
    > aG9saWRheXNwcmVtaWVyLmVqZWN1dGl2bzE0QGdtYWlsLmNvbQBob2xpZGF5c3ByZW1pZXIuZWplY3V0aXZvMTRAZ21haWwuY29tAGZpd2p0ZnFhaHJ4Zm55cnU=
    < * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584
    < C OK hmyuser@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
    Etc................................................................
```

then everything it is ok whit the network since I ran that from the server which it is on a VM
 then

```
    $ php -v
    PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Aug 28 2019 15:03:50) 
    Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies 

    $ httpd -v
    Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
    Server built:   Aug  8 2019 11:41:18
```

With packages installed 
php-imap

```
<?php 

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = 'myuser@gmail.com';
$password = 'mypassword';

$mbx = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password)or die('Cannot connect: ' . print_r(imap_errors($mbx)));

?>
```

the weird thing is this

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /var/www/html/imap/connect.php on line 8

Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Permission denied (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Permission denied (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Permission denied (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

but if I do

```
if (function_exists('imap_open')) {
    echo "IMAP functions are available.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "IMAP functions are not available.<br />\n";
}
```

it gives IMAP functions are available.

on the log from html

```
[Fri Sep 20 20:49:59.706418 2019] [:error] [pid 1844] [client 192.168.100.19:58086] PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /var/www/html/imap/connect.php on line 8, referer: http://myserver.com/imap/connect.php
[Fri Sep 20 20:49:59.706727 2019] [:error] [pid 1844] [client 192.168.100.19:58086] PHP Notice:  Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Permission denied (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://myserver.com/imap/
[Fri Sep 20 20:49:59.706761 2019] [:error] [pid 1844] [client 192.168.100.19:58086] PHP Notice:  Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Permission denied (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://myserver.com/imap/
[Fri Sep 20 20:49:59.706789 2019] [:error] [pid 1844] [client 192.168.100.19:58086] PHP Notice:  Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Permission denied (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://myserver.com/imap/
```

I was thinking about and figured out it should be something whit SELinux and then

```
`$ setenforce 0`
```

and

```
` $ getenforce
Permissive`
```

and try again an it works but I don't want have SELinux Disable

then i find

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Source 
https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

Hope This Helps Someone ! ;)

Comment: If you wish to share knowledge, a self-answered question is a good way: Phrase your question as a question, then post an answer with your findings and work around.  We'd rather you not put your answer in the question portion.

Comment: ok well i did that because no one answer my question sadly and I went working on the problem and the editor it is easier use or better if you like to said that and i though it is better read continuously then read answer by answer, I appreciate you note ! Max